# css transitions determine new assigned value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
div {
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-duration: 2s;
  }
```

The above example defines a transition on the 'opacity' property that, when a new value is assigned to it, will cause a smooth change between the old value and the new value over a period of two seconds. (с) w3c http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/ 
How can I determine with jQuery/javascript this new value? Only by parse stylesheet or there is more convenient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value of the opacity with jQuery's css function, see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/RTd3c/ (click OK on the alert boxes quickly!).

Is this what you were after?